# How i can i pull fields top comment form bottom

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2nAR.png)

How  can i put comment field bottom and name email website fields can stay on top Here is my following code.

```
$commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();

        $fields = array(

            'author' =>
                '<div class="form-group"><label for="author">' . __( 'Name', 'hanford' ) . '</label> <span class="required">*</span> <input id="author" name="author" type="text" class="form-control" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" required="required" /></div>',

            'email' =>
                '<div class="form-group"><label for="email">' . __( 'Email', 'hanford' ) . '</label> <span class="required">*</span><input id="email" name="email" class="form-control" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" required="required" /></div>',

            'url' =>
                '<div class="form-group last-field"><label for="url">' . __( 'Website', 'hanford' ) . '</label><input id="url" name="url" class="form-control" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" /></div>'

        );

        $args = array(

            'class_submit' => '',
            'label_submit' => __( 'Post Comment' ),
            'comment_field' =>
                '<div class="form-group"><label for="comment">' . _x( 'Comment', 'hanford' ) . '</label> <span class="required">*</span><textarea id="comment" class="form-control" name="comment" rows="4" required="required"></textarea></p>',
            'fields' => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', $fields )

        );

        comment_form( $args );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can used `comment_form_fields` filter. Please add below code in you `function.php` file. for more information [click here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-comment-text-field-to-bottom-in-wordpress-4-4/)

```
function wpb_move_comment_field_to_bottom( $fields ) {
    $comment_field = $fields['comment'];
    unset( $fields['comment'] );
    //print_r($fields);
    $fields['comment'] = $comment_field;
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'comment_form_fields', 'wpb_move_comment_field_to_bottom',99,1 );
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention its worked but i have one question as you see i shared photo my comments.php codes. when i creating input fields i must create on fucntions.php or on comments .php ?

Comment: creating input fields on comments.php file

Comment: Thank you so much.